# getting undefined at random times

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, canvas, tetris

i will try to add only relevant code but just in case its needed full page is [here](http://borisute.com/geshem/2013/mkeller/tetris.html), and feel free to check it out on [github](https://github.com/mendelthegeek/my-canvas-tetris) as well.

i am building a tetris game using canvas/javascript and part of it

```
    //drop the falling piece by one space
function dropByOne(){
        //loop through the four squares that make up the piece
    for ( i = 3; i > -1; i-- ) {
            //empty old spot of piece
        board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ] = 0;
            //drop position place-holder by one row
        fallingPiecePos[i].y++;
            //add square to new spot
        board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ] = fallingPiece;
    }
}
```

`board` is a 20*10 `array`, `fallingPiecePos` is a array of objects with numerical `x` and `y` values, i.e. `[{y:0,x:4},{y:0,x:5},{y:0,x:6},{y:0,x:7}]` (line piece) or `[{y:0,x:4},{y:0,x:5},{y:1,x:4},{y:1,x:5}]` (square) that are rendered into `board` with the following code:

```
for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
    board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ] = fallingPiece;
}
```

`fallingPiece` is a randomly assigned number (1-7) used by `canvas` to render the piece as the right color.

hope thats clear enough, now the problem is that whenever `fallingPiece` has a value it has had before i get

```
TypeError: board[fallingPiecePos[i].y] is undefined
[Break On This Error]   

board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ] = fallingPiece;
```

(`board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ] = fallingPiece;` is the last line of above code-block)

i have a [function `nothingIsBelow()`](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/7uwMH/) which checks if the piece has reached the bottom, so i am pretty stumped as to why this is happening.

### edit

i wasnt clear enough on this point before **it works fine the first 3-4 pieces (aside for piece collision protection) *and only gives me above error when `fallingPiece` has a previously held value***

### edit

it seems that the issue is like this i have a array `shapes`

```
var shapes = [
    [{y:0,x:4},{y:0,x:5},{y:0,x:6},{y:0,x:7}],
    [{y:0,x:4},{y:0,x:5},{y:0,x:6},{y:1,x:4}],
    [{y:0,x:4},{y:0,x:5},{y:0,x:6},{y:1,x:5}],
    [{y:0,x:4},{y:0,x:5},{y:0,x:6},{y:1,x:6}],
    [{y:0,x:4},{y:0,x:5},{y:1,x:4},{y:1,x:5}],
    [{y:0,x:4},{y:0,x:5},{y:1,x:3},{y:1,x:4}],
    [{y:0,x:4},{y:0,x:5},{y:1,x:5},{y:1,x:6}]
];
```

and i have a line of code assigning a shape to a new piece

```
fallingPiecePos = shapes[fallingPiece - 1];
```

it seems that when i later refer to `fallingPiecePos` and change the value (`fallingPiecePos[i].y++;`), it changes the value in `shapes` as well

**in simple terms** the following code

```
var myArray = [
     [{a:0,b:1},{a:1,b:1}],
     [{a:0,b:0},{a:1,b:0}]
];

var foo = myArray[0];

foo[0].a++;
console.log(myArray[0][0][a]);
```

will give me `1` because not only `foo` but also `myArray` was updated, so how can i make a variable which holds a **new** array (`foo`) holding the values of `myArray[0]` and can be updated without updating `myArray[0]`.

Comment: If you put `console.log(board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ]);` before the line creating the error, what does it say the values are? I think debugging using the console would be the best approach here. any chance of a jsFiddle?

Comment: @Zeaklous too much code for a fiddle, i tried some debugging b4 i came here, and i get the same error with `console.log(board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ]);` i hope thats enough info

Comment: Console is not a fix for a solution, it is a tool used to investigate objects and find errors. It's a staple for web programming in general. [**See this for more information**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console)

Comment: @Zeaklous im not a noob, i know what `console` is what i meant was that when it reaches that line it gives me the same error and doesnt `log` anything

Comment: @Zeaklous copy-paste from `console` - `tetris.js (line 70)
0
tetris.js (line 70)
0
tetris.js (line 70)
0
tetris.js (line 70)
0
tetris.js (line 70)
0
tetris.js (line 70)
0
tetris.js (line 70)
3
tetris.js (line 70)
3
tetris.js (line 70)
0
tetris.js (line 70)
0
tetris.js (line 70)
0
tetris.js (line 70)
3
tetris.js (line 70)
0
tetris.js (line 70)
3
tetris.js (line 70)
TypeError: board[fallingPiecePos[i].y] is undefined
[Break On This Error]  

console.log(board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ]);

tetris.js (line 70)`

Comment: You're right - I thought I was able to repro it with even a first time `fallingPiece` value, but this was not the case. I've updated my answer below (you seem to be modifying the values in your `shapes` array when a piece falls, which results with you referencing board[20] which does not exist).

Comment: @spectralbat thanks i have realized that on my own now, check my edited question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are modifying your `shapes` array. When a particular piece falls and you update its position you actually update that array as opposed to just `fallingPiecePos` exclusively. This means that when piece `n` falls the first time, it stops at row `board[19]`, but when it is chosen again it ends up in `board[20]`, which does not exist.

You can check this by checking the contents of your shapes array when you run the game - note that the positions change. To fix this you'd need to either avoid modifying your array of shapes for each piece or resetting the array values each time a piece is chosen.

Example:

```
function writePiece() { 
    var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(shapes)); 
    fallingPiecePos = copy[fallingPiece - 1]; 
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) { 
        board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ] = fallingPiece; 
    } 
}
```

Comment: thanks u found the problem (by now i found it 2), can u help me with a solution plz (edited question - `so how can i make a variable which holds a new array (foo) holding the values of myArray[0] and can be updated without updating myArray[0].`)

Comment: You have to clone the object instead of just creating a reference to it. There are a few different methods, but I usually use a variant of the selected answer here, which also comes with a wonderful in-depth explanation: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/728360/most-elegant-way-to-clone-a-javascript-object

Comment: from looking those over the simplest thing i see (for my case at least) is using a `for` loop, is there a more instinctual method? and i can accept your answer if you add some working (replacement) code.

Comment: tried replacing `function writePiece(){
 fallingPiecePos = shapes[fallingPiece - 1];
 for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
  board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ] = fallingPiece;
 }
}` with `function writePiece(){
 fallingPiecePos = [];
 for ( var i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
 fallingPiecePos[i] = {};
  for( var j in shapes[fallingPiece - 1]){
   fallingPiecePos[i][j] = shapes[fallingPiece - 1][j];
  }
  board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ] = fallingPiece;
 }
}` and its not working, could you please give me a solution for my specific case?

Comment: sorry for not writing  code clearly [fiddle with both functions here](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/uhEg9/)

Comment: Villarrealized's answer would actually work.

function writePiece(){
    var copy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(shapes));
    fallingPiecePos = copy[fallingPiece - 1];
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ] = fallingPiece;
    }
}

Comment: thanks, works perfectly, if u add that in your actual answer i will accept it

Answer (score 3):

"*board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ] is undefined*", meaning whatever value that `fallingPiecePos[i].y` is at that point in time, it is *out of the range* of `board` array.

I took a quick look and it always seems to throw error on the 4th tetromino piece because it's trying to draw it on (x, 20) position on `board` (`fallingPiecePos[i].y` at that point is 20), when the `board` can only draw up to row 19, remember indices start at 0 and not 1.

I would suggest you fix your `nothingIsBelow` function to check whether the tetromino has "settled" on top of another tetromino or the bottom edge of the game screen. Before dropping the current tetromino into place.

Comment: i didnt include the code of `nothingIsBelow()` because its a bit long [here is a fiddle of that function](http://jsfiddle.net/mendelthecoder/7uwMH/) as for _it always seems to throw error on the 4th tetromino piece because it's trying to draw it on (x, 20) position on board_ as i said in my question "now the problem is that whenever `fallingPiece` **has a value it has had before**" which i think is a bit weird

Answer (score 0):

Modify your write piece function to look like this:

Check out the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RJe86/11/ -- no errors

```
function writePiece(){
    var shapeCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(shapes));
    fallingPiecePos = shapeCopy[fallingPiece - 1];
    for ( i = 0; i < 4; i++ ) {
        board[ fallingPiecePos[i].y ][ fallingPiecePos[i].x ] = fallingPiece;
    }
}
```

That should fix it.